# Bootstrap Toggle Button Appears but doesn't work and Navbar doesn't collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Toggle Button appears, but doesn't work and Navbar doesn't collapse either for some reason. I'm not sure why it isn't working. I've posted my code below. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
   <!--HEADER ===========================================================================-->
    <header class="site-header" role="banner">
        <!-- NAVBAR ======================================================================-->
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="img/jadslogo.png" alt="JADS"></a>
                    </div><!-- end navbar-header -->
                    <div="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/">Donate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/">Get Involved</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- end navbar-right -->
                    </div><!-- end nvbar navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- end container -->                
            </div><!-- end navbar...fixed top -->
        </div><!-- end navbar-wrapper -->
    </header>
```

Comment: I found one error <div="navbar-collapse collapse"> should be <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

Comment: just found out that I needed I needed to list my jquery link BEFORE my bootstrap link and now my drop down list is working.

Comment: My question is now solved.